# Common licencing types

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-recommendation

I'm an independent software developer and thus have little to no knowledge about licenses or general software law.

**Could someone list the most common licenses and what they mean in layman's therms.**

Comment: See, for example, https://its.uncg.edu/Software/Licensing/

Comment: I believe that goes for universities, I'm more interested in entrepreneurial aspect.

Comment: I'd also like to see the differences between different GPL licenses

Comment: Either you did not search enough (at least the first four results of https://www.google.fr/search?q=license+list are interesting) or you are looking for something more specific. In that case, please make your question more specific.

Comment: The list is too comprehensive, there's too many licenses and i have no idea what most of them entail, even after reading the whole page of text. I'm just not a type for legal matters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this site http://oss-watch.ac.uk/apps/licdiff/ It's a Licence differentiator of various Free & Open source licenses.

or try this for the difference between most commonly used Open source licenses.
 http://choosealicense.com/licenses/